# Filter pk that before url_path in ListApiView. Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have `urlpatterns += [path('collection/<int:pk>/video/', CollectionVideoViewSet.as_view(),name='collection-videos')]`.

And `ListAPIView`:

```
class CollectionVideoViewSet(ListAPIView):

    """ViewSet for operation with videos in collection"""
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CollectionVideoSerializer
```

Can i filter queryset in this view by `pk`?

So, I want to have count, next, previous fields in output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `get_queryset` method:

```py
class CollectionVideoViewSet(ListAPIView):
    """ViewSet for operation with videos in collection"""
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CollectionVideoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Assuming your `Video` model has a many-to-one relation to `Collection`
        return self.queryset.filter(
            collection__pk=self.kwargs['pk']
        )
```

In order to make your view return a paginated result, i.e. count, next, previous, you need to define a `pagination_class` in your view:

```py
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CollectionVideoViewSet(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

More about [pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#api-reference) in DRF

Answer (score 0):

Yep, override **get_queryset** method of **ListAPIView**

```
class TeamList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TeamSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sc = EmployeeSearchCriteria(email=self.kwargs["email"], role=Employee.VIEWER)
        return EmployeeCalculatorService().get_team_by_employee(sc)
```

Comment: in this situation, will I have count, next, previous fields in the returned information?

Comment: yep, it is done via different methods that you don't override